# Harmonics of Ethernet (100MBps) MLT-3 signals

Tags: ethernet, emc, harmonics, radiation, rj45

I have EMC Issue (Radiation) as attached..where at some frequencies the emission levels are exceeding the limits..
I use 36V power and Ethernet (MLT3) for communication.
These failing frequencies are not correlating to any of the system switching powersupplies in the system.
Here are my questions

1. Is it possible the two diff frequency emissions, can get modulated in far field and show as diff freq levels?
2. What are harmonics of MLT3 100Mbps signals
3. I am wondering if the MLT3 ethernet signal harmonics coupling through powersupply and radiating allover..
4. I see radiated emission failure as below

   Freq (Mhz)  Exceeding (dB)
   32.64       6.1
   41.00       2.8
   67.00       -1.5(marginal)
   125.00      0.8
   173.75      4.2
   225.01      2.8
   274.98      -5.3 (marginal)
   774.99      0.8
   824.98      0.9

In these the 125, 225, 274.98, 274.98, 774.99, 824.98..I can correlate that these are multiple of 25Mhz,
which is ref clock for phy and ethernet controller.
Other frequencies, am not able to correlate to any switching frequencies in the board
Any clue would be helpful[image]

Comment: EMC is a holistic topic. An answer may be possible, but potentially *everything* in your system must be under consideration. The more complete a picture we have of that system, the better an answer we can provide. There is essentially nothing in this question as currently written; we certainly can't offer any clues about other frequencies. Please provide complete schematics, layout, and mechanical or assembly drawings of the system, or absolutely everything you possibly can provide.

Comment: Sure will provide..Can you share me your email id so I can provide restricted access to the gdrive folder?

Comment: Restricted access implies no one else would be able to answer; nor would readers be able to understand the circumstances of your problem, nor the relevance of the answer. If you aren't able to share data publicly, might I suggest engaging a local EMI consultant?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible the two diff frequency emissions, can get modulated in far field and show as diff freq levels?

No. "Far field" usually describes "waves in air", and air is for all practical matters here a linear medium, and hence, you can't get power at new frequencies.

Two sources of power at the same frequency can add up, however.

> What are harmonics of MLT3 100Mbps signals

MLT3 doesn't matter for the spectrum, only the symbol rate and pulse shape does. (that is one of the fundamental facts about modulations ;) )

The symbol rate going of Fast Ethernet 100Base-TX (which is *probably* what you mean when you say "MLT3 100 Mbps", but that's not sure, your specification is insufficient) to the PHY is at 31.25 MHz (that's actually stated on Wikipedia! Own research is king!), so you get that, and all multiples of that, as harmonics – the quadruple of it is actually the symbol rate.

> I am wondering if the MLT3 ethernet signal harmonics coupling through powersupply and radiating allover..

You've paid a measurement provider to figure that one out!

> am not able to correlate to any switching frequencies in the board Any clue would be helpful

Impossible to tell for us, who don't have physical access to your board. I'd say: time to get your oscilloscope out and start probing!